# Secure way to perform SQL query in C# class library?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm developing NuGet package as a side project. With the package, the user will be able to retrieve data from my MySQL database server by executing a function that contains SQL query in it - let's call it `GetStuff()`.

Example of the GetStuff code:

```
 public class GetStuff : IDisposable {

    public string? name;


    public void Dispose() {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public GetStuff() {

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Server...");

            ConnectionGetter.con.Open();

            String _select = "SELECT stuff FROM information;";
            ConnectionGetter.command = new MySqlCommand(_select, ConnectionGetter.con);

            MySqlDataReader _read = ConnectionGetter.command.ExecuteReader();
            while (_read.Read()) {
                name = _read.GetString(0);
            }
            _read.Close();
    }
```

Example usage:

```
   String myUsername = "";
        using(GetStuff gs = new GetStuff()) {
            myUsername = gs.name;
        }
```

ConnectionGetter class will retrieve connection string from App.Config:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Test {
    public class ConnectionGetter {
        private static string access = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTIONSETUP"].ConnectionString;
        public static MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(access);
        public static MySqlCommand command;
    }
}
```

And the main problem is that the SQL query is exposed when you're using IntelliSense, and I want to avoid my table, column, or anything that's related to the SQL query from the function from getting exposed to the user. Am I doing this wrong? What is safer way to do this so the user cannot see the SQL query code behind the function?

Comment: Even if you perfectly obfuscated your code so query texts couldn't be read, the user can intercept them quite easily with a packet sniffer. If you need to keep the structure of your database "secret", don't expose it directly as a database server. On the other hand, if your have properly secured your database and enabled access only through specific views that you maintain, it shouldn't be a concern that the user can see it. If your server allows a user to log in directly, you should always assume they're capable of executing any command they like, as they don't need to use your library.

Comment: On the whole people tend to frown on the idea of exposing a database server directly to end users, and with good reason; this is much harder to secure, audit and scale than, say, an online web API specifically built for this purpose.

Comment: You are developing a nuget package? This is supposed to be installed by endusers, right? So does this package access a remote db Server (or your server)? If yes, you have already lost because you will have to provide credentials for that server somehow. And no obfuscation whatever can secure those credentials...

Comment: Create a REST API or similar and provide the user with credentials for that REST API. But don't let anyone but that service access your DB server, especially not random people from all over the world

Comment: Side note: do *not* cache connection and command objects. Create when needed, dispose with `using` . Same for the reader object.